# Python: split a string using ONLY multiple spaces or single newline

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a table of items that is structured in the following way:

```
TABLE: 
1 the quick                                     brown fox
3 jumped over                                 4 lazy dog
```

or

```
'1 the quick               brown fox\n3 jumped over           4 lazy dog'
```

I'd like to parse this table and extract the number that corresponds to a specific item given a name. For instance I would input `'over'` or `'jumped over'` and my function would output `'3'`. Depending on the generation of the table, items may or may not have numbers next to them.

My current idea is to split the table using regular expression at either multiple spaces or newline but since `re.split('[\s{2,},\n]', table)` doesn't work because the curly brackets are evaluated literally, I am instead using `re.split('\n*\s{2,}', re.sub('\n', '\n  ', table))` and adding in spaces after newlines simply to force it to fit the pattern.

This method seems ugly and very un-python-y. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my current implementation within a function:

```
def table_parser(search_term, table):
    options = re.split('\n*\s{2,}', re.sub('\n', '\n  ', table))
    choices = [item for item in options if re.search(search_term, item, re.IGNORECASE) and re.search('\d+', item)]

    if len(choices) > 1:
        raise Error
    elif len(choices) == 0:
        raise AnotherError
    else:
        num = re.search('(\d+)',choices[0]).group(1)
    return num
```

If I've done anything else a long and stupid way, please feel free to comment but the main issue is the parsing of the table :)

Comment: What if the input is `brown`?

Comment: If the input is brown it should throw an error

Comment: @JeffP why it would return an error?

Comment: @AvinashRaj by "should" I mean "I'd like it to". My implementation does throw an error because no match is found.

Comment: Picking nits, because this is a serious peeve of mine, but it's "The quick brown fox **jumps** over the lazy dog", otherwise it's not a pangram (no "s").

Comment: Geeze... why all the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """TABLE: 
1 the quick                                     brown fox
3 jumped over                                 4 lazy dog"""
>>> input1 = input('Please provide the string you want to search:\n')
Please provide the string:
over
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)\D*' + input1, s).group(1)
'3'
>>> input1 = input('Please provide the string:\n')
Please provide the string:
jumped over
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)\D*' + input1, s).group(1)
'3'
```

For the input brown, it would return the number `1` as output.

```
>>> input1 = input('Please provide the string:\n')
Please provide the string:
brown
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)\D*' + input1, s).group(1)
'1'
```

update:

```
>>> lst = re.split(r'\s{2,}|\n', s)
>>> input1 = input('Please provide the string:\n')
Please provide the string:
over
>>> for i in lst:
        if re.search(r'(\d+)\D*' + input1, i):
            print(re.search(r'(\d+)\D*' + input1, i).group(1))


3
```

Comment: This is close but it doesn't account for if an option isn't available, such as if 'brown' was requested (I'd like it to throw an error if that were the case).

Comment: Yep! Thanks! I completely forgot about the | character. I think that does it